# How to define icon for jupyterlab extension?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-lab

I want to create my own Jupyterlab extension.
Where can I define the icon used in the extension manager?
And where can I find documentation about that?

Could not find in

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/extension_dev.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the icon is taken from the homepage that is
specified in package.json, e.g.

"homepage": https://github.com/kiteco/jupyterlab-kite

=> icon: https://github.com/kiteco.png